# is it possible to integrate offline search and indexing document in android app using solr or something else?

Tags: android, python-2.7, elasticsearch, indexing, solr

i am looking for something, which will index documents and search offline in native android app.

i never worked on android but having knowledge of solr, elasticsearch, python, java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do a lucene search?

Comment: Thanks.. i am trying same now...

Comment: i tried lucene but lt's not fully supported by android, any other way to index document and search results from it?

Comment: what do you mean it's not fully supported by android